# Htaccess: Language Detection Among with clean URL

Tags: .htaccess

I want to write a RewriteRule that both cleans the URL and puts the language detection before the file.

I have looked at questions like [.htaccess for language detection, redirecting + clean urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21453052/htaccess-for-language-detection-redirecting-clean-urls) and [.htaccess rule for language detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16854820/htaccess-rule-for-language-detection).

With these two combined I made a solution that sometimes works and sometimes doesn't.

My structure: `domain.com/subfolder/news.php?lang=en`

What I want is: `domain.com/subfolder/en/news`

My code so far:

```
RewriteBase /subfolder/
    
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    # Language Detection
    RewriteRule ^(en|sv)/(.*)$  $2?lang=$1 [QSA,L]
    ## Remove .php extensions
    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]`
```

This did work on some paths, but not on all (they had the same structure).

How should I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
RewriteBase /subfolder/

# Language Detection
RewriteRule ^(en|sv)/(.*)$  $2?lang=$1 [NC,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
## Remove .php extensions
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(en|sv)/(.*)$  $2?lang=$1 [L,NC,QSA]` Added the "L" and that order did work, thanks!